# DynamoDB if_not_exists on UpdateItem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying a very simple scenario.  I need to maintain a counter per row. I am using UpdateItem to do upsert instead of insert.

1. If row does not exist, it should just set the value of counter column
2. If row exists, it should update the counter.

2 works fine, but for 1 it complains that attribute does not exist.  I tried if_not_exists clause without any help.  Can someone please point me to the right direction?  Also share how to use if_not_exists clause for UpdateItem

Comment: Figured it out.  Used ADD operation instead of SET operation to update the counter during upsert

Comment: Could you please give me the solution for -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46668886/update-an-item-adding-an-attribute-in-dynamodb

Answer (score 8):

You could use the DynamoDb update expression like this:

```
SET #param = if_not_exists(#param, :num0) + :num1
```

Where `:num0` - default value and `:num1` - number to add. Please, be aware that the value after the first DynamoDb update operation of the field `param` would be `:num0` **+** `:num1`

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out. Used ADD operation instead of SET operation to update the counter during upsert

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html