# update an item adding an attribute in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it not possible to add an attribute in dynamodb dynamically?

I got this error when I tried-"**The provided key element does not match the schema**".

Scenario -

```
{ id : "123",
  imageName : "elephant.jpg"
}
```

I want to add an attribute - imagePath : "/path/to/image" to the above data.
I used put_item, but it replaces the old item if exists.

I am searching for the solution for - If id = "123", then add imagePath attribute else add a new item to the table.

Adding an attribute can be achieved using put_item but it will replace the existing item. **How can we dynamically add an attribute to the existing data using update_item ?** (appending imagePath to the the given json)

**Should I alter the schema of the table with imagePath and then use update_item function?**

How can we achieve this using python?

Comment: What is the code do you use?

Comment: @Kannaiyan I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it can't be achieved in single step. However, it can be achieved in two step process:-

1) Try to insert the data conditionally i.e. if the key value is already present don't perform any operation (i.e. insert or update - nothing happens)

2) If there is a `ConditionalCheckFailedException`, then update the item

**Sample code:-**

In the below code, `usertable` is the table name. The key attributes of the table are `userid` and `score`. You need to change the below code accordingly for your table structure.

Also, I have assigned the key value (as "Mike"). You need to change it accordingly for your use case.

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
from boto.dynamodb2.exceptions import ConditionalCheckFailedException
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr
import boto3
import json
import decimal

# Helper class to convert a DynamoDB item to JSON.
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if o % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            else:
                return int(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")

table = dynamodb.Table('usertable')

userId = "Mike"

try :
    response = table.put_item(
    Item={
            'userid': userId,
            'score' : 100,
            'imagePath' : '/path/to/image'        
        },
        ConditionExpression=Attr('userid').ne(userId)        
    )

    print("Conditional PutItem succeeded:")
    print(json.dumps(response, indent=4, cls=DecimalEncoder))
except ClientError as ce :    
    print("Conditional check failed:", ce)
    if ce.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ConditionalCheckFailedException':
        print("Key already exists")
        response = table.update_item(
            Key={'userid': userId, 'score' : 100},
            UpdateExpression="set imagePath = :imagePathVal",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={":imagePathVal" : "/path/to/image" }
        )
        print("Update existing item succeeded:")
        print(json.dumps(response, indent=4, cls=DecimalEncoder))        
    else:
        print("Unexpected error: %s" % e
```

)

**Update:-**

The data type of variable `id` and key attribute `RequestId` should match.

Comment: the expect block will still give error "The provided key element does not match the schema", because imagePath is the dynamic field which I am trying to add (imagePath  is not in the table schema). What is the solution for this? @notionquest

Comment: Dynamodb accepts dynamic fields. You dont need to define all the fields in schema. In the update item api, you need to use the key attributes correctly. What is your partition key and sort key?

Comment: Your partition key attribute name is RequestId or Id?

Comment: My update function - table.update_item(Key = {'RequestId' : id, 'Source' : 'Ironwood' }, UpdateExpression = 'SET ImagePath = :value1', ExpressionAttributeValues = {':value1': imagePath}). RequestId is the partition key and Source is the sort key.

Comment: RequestId is the partition key is and Source is the sort key. I have put id in the question is for understanding.

Comment: The above update item looks good. Are you still getting error ? Please make sure that attribute names are case sensitive. Do you have the keys defined in the same case as mentioned in update item?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156451/discussion-between-manojpt-and-notionquest).

Answer (score 1):

Lastest version of update_item will handle attribute creation if does not already exists

```
import boto3 
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

def query_status(asset_id, dynamodb, table):
    try:        
        response = table.query(
            ProjectionExpression="#asset_id, status_id" ,
            ExpressionAttributeNames={"#asset_id": "asset_id"},
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('asset_id').eq(asset_id)        
        )
        if response['Items']:
            return response['Items'][0]["status_id"]
    except:
        pass # if attribute does not exists, return None

    
 
def update_asset_status(asset_id, status_id, dynamodb, table):  
    response = table.update_item(
        Key={'asset_id': asset_id},
        UpdateExpression="set status_id=:r",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':r': status_id},
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
    return response



dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('assets')

asset_id='1234'

print("Current Status: ", query_status(asset_id, dynamodb, table))

new_status_id='4'
update_asset_status(asset_id, new_status_id, dynamodb, table)

print("New Status: ", query_status(id, dynamodb, table))
```